# Linearize Non-Linear Optimization Constraints

Tags: optimization, linearization

I'm trying to add a non-linear constraint to my model that describes as the amount of heated water (`m_heated` @ `temp_heated`) required to add to other cold/inlet/network water mass (`m_inlet` @ `temp_inlet`) to result in a defined temperature `temp_set`. The total flow rate `m_total` is total mixture, given by adding both flow rates `m_total = m_heated + m_inlet`. Assuming the same fluid, so I'm disregarding the specific heat capacity.

```
temp_set = ( m_heated * temp_heated + (m_total - m_heated) * temp_inlet ) / m_total
```

Since my goal is to find the m_heated (to add to the optimization problem), this simplifies to:

```
m_heated[t] = m_total * (temp_set - temp_inlet) / (temp_heated[t] - temp_inlet)
```

However, this results in a non-linear equation (`m_total`, `temp_set`, `temp_inlet` are known), and both `m_heated` and `temp_heated` are not, and they add to other constrains as well.

Both `m_heated` and `temp_heated` values add to a second restriction that calculates the stored energy (kWh) in the heater:

```
heater_energy[t] = m_heated[t] * c * (temp_heated[t] - temp_inlet)) / 3600
```

However, this restriction also show up as non-linear. I've tried the approach found *AIMMS Modeling Guide - Integer Programming Tricks*, but I was not able to comprehend it completly. All [t] variables are continuous.

Any clue how to convert these expressions into linear?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can either follow what given in the AIMM Integer Tricks (Pg85, Ch-7) or you can try this trick
For two continuous variables $ 0 \le a, b$, define another continuous variable $0\le z$ and a constraint
$ a+b = z$
Then replace $ab$ wherever it appears with $ z^2 - (a^2+b^2)$. Most solvers will handle squares in constraints. As for squares in objective these can be replaced by another variable $y$ supported by a constraint like $ z^2 = y$